# How to hide node labels in pyvis network?

Tags: pyvis

I have a network with around 100 nodes which are highly connected. Now, the all the labels look very messy. I tried to remove the `label` setting the label attribute to `None` or `''`, but then the id's are shown instead. Is there a way to hide the labels or only show the labels of selected nodes and edges?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs (https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyvis/network.html) I see that the `add_node` method of the `Network` class contains the logical test `if label`. This will evaluate to `False` if label is `None` or an empty string (`""`), but will evaluate to `True` if you use try to approximate an empty string with nothing but a space `" "`.

Failing the above, you could try editing the code in `add_node`, or (perhaps preferably) defining your own `Network` that inherits from the original and over-writes the `add_node` method. Maybe something like this:

```
from pyvis.network import Network

class AbsoluteLabelNetwork(Network):
    """A version of the pyvis.network.Network class that always uses the label provided"""
    def add_node(self, n_id, label=None, shape="dot", **options):
        """See parent class for docstr, with the exception that label will always be used"""
        assert isinstance(n_id, str) or isinstance(n_id, int)
        node_label = label  # note: change from package version
        if n_id not in self.node_ids:
            n = Node(n_id, shape, label=node_label, font_color=self.font_color, **options)
            self.nodes.append(n.options)
            self.node_ids.append(n_id)
```

Please note that these possible solutions are untested so I'd be interested if they helped you.

Comment: Thanks I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the labels by setting a transparent font color. For example like this:

```
from pyvis.network import Network

net = Network(font_color='#10000000')
net.from_nx(G)
net.show('example.html')
```

This makes all the node labels disappear in my case (Technically they are still there, but they are not visible anymore).